# Magento 2.1.8 export not working

Tags: product, export, magento-2.1.8

I try to export my products in Magento 2.1.8. When i select to export products and csv files format and i press continue then showing '**Please correct the data sent value**.'

Log file error:

> [2018-11-26 07:44:21] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Notice: A non well
>   formed numeric value encountered in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Export/Product.php
>   on line 773 in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack
>   trace:

Does anyone know what caused this issue?

Comment: I have solved this by activating "set_time_limit" on my server, after debugging a few hours...

Comment: The sentence becomes fragment after edit. It is an incomplete sentence now.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/154066)

Answer (score 2):

I have face same issue and resolved using below solution and every thing working fine

please change some code in below file small "m" to capital "M".

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Export/Product.php

```
protected function getItemsPerPage() {
        if ($this->_itemsPerPage === null) {
            $memoryLimit = trim(ini_get('memory_limit'));
            $lastMemoryLimitLetter = strtolower($memoryLimit[strlen($memoryLimit) - 1]);
            switch ($lastMemoryLimitLetter) {
            case 'g':
                $memoryLimit *= 1024;
            // fall-through intentional
            case 'm':
                $memoryLimit *= 1024;
            // fall-through intentional
            case 'k':
                $memoryLimit *= 1024;
                break;
            default:
                // minimum memory required by Magento
                $memoryLimit = 250000000;
            }
To

protected function getItemsPerPage() {
        if ($this->_itemsPerPage === null) {
            $memoryLimit = trim(ini_get('memory_limit'));
            $lastMemoryLimitLetter = strtolower($memoryLimit[strlen($memoryLimit) - 1]);
            switch ($lastMemoryLimitLetter) {
            case 'g':
                $memoryLimit *= 1024;
            // fall-through intentional
            case 'M':
                $memoryLimit *= 1024;
            // fall-through intentional
            case 'k':
                $memoryLimit *= 1024;
                break;
            default:
                // minimum memory required by Magento
                $memoryLimit = 250000000;
            }
```

Comment: As per mention above change but not working in My Magento 2.2.5. Can you tell me another solution?

Comment: Thanks, it worked in Magento 2.2.5 pretty weird.

Comment: I am installed Magento using GitHub INstallation, my Magento configuration under app/code/magento, where i can find  Product.php?